# What do B and H stand for in a magnetic BH curve?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology

I can't seem to find what the B and H stand for in a magnetic BH curve. I understand B is magnetic flux density and H is amperes/meter, but why are the letters B and H used? Why not A and B? Why is it called a BH curve and not an AB curve?

Comment: Some hints [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/where-does-the-symbol-b-for-magnetic-flux-density-come-from.114652/).

Answer (score 18):

According to Youtuber "[Kathy Loves Physics & History](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5dhRgeZYHA)"  the original use of B and H was in James Clerk Maxwell's "[A treatise on Electricity and Magnetism](https://www.aproged.pt/biblioteca/MaxwellI.pdf)".

But note Heaviside's contribution to the definitions.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

According to [A Treatise On Electricity Magnetism-Volume2](https://archive.org/details/electricandmag02maxwrich/page/n31/mode/2up)

Maxwell simply named his quantities alphabetically.

| symbol | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| A | vector potential |
| B | magnetic field B |
| C | total current (through a cross section) |
| D | electric displacement field |
| E | electric field |
| F | force density (f = ρE + JxB) |
| G | velocity in a point |
| H | magnetic field H |
| I | magnetization M |
| J | current density |

Some survived into modern use, some didn't.

Comment: E, B, and J are the only ones in _the_ Maxwell equations, which would explain why they survived.

Comment: @OrangeDog The very original formulation of the Maxwell equations was quite obscure for a strange kind of fictitious fluid (using quaternions). Depending whether you only count the vacuum Maxwell equations or not. The versions for other media are also very common and hence H and D (at least from the version stated in the table above) survived as well. Arguments can be made whether *the* Maxwell's equations are those published by Maxwell or those that theoreticians like as the most basic now, but I do not think such arguments are fruitful.

Answer (score 13):

There's apparently no real reason behind the letters.

[This blog post](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/why-the-symbol-for-magnetic-field-is-b-e40658e17ece) shows an excerpt from a book by Maxwell from 1873.  It defines a set of vectors and assigns each a letter for use in equations.  There's no deeper meaning to each letter than its position in the list.

[image]

The same list can be found on pages 236 and 237 of the copy of *A Treatise On Electricity Magnetism-Volume2* that [Neil_UK linked to in another answer.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/699997/47070)

[image]

The letter names of those vectors have become standard - everyone uses them.  The only reason not to use your own letter (or Greek letter or custom squiggle) is because no one will know what you mean.  You could call them Fred and Barney if you wanted to, you'd just have explain to everyone you communicate with that Fred is H and Barney is B.

Comment: I'm glad we can just say B and H now, at least, instead of having to go into the character map to find  and .

Comment: Oh come on, it would be much clearer if Fred was B and Barney was H.

Comment: @ThePhoton: 

Comment: `\$\mathcal B,\ \mathcal H\$` renders as \$\mathcal B,\ \mathcal H\$.